# window.location.hash issue when working with jQuery tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three forms on a page within three separate tabs. Each tab is uniquely identified as necessary when using jQuery tabs.

When I submit a form I display a thank you message and then redirect the page back to the initial page with the three tabs.

On setting the location back to the original page I want it to automatically go to the tab that the form was submitted from.

I have tried the following:

```
setTimeout(setToDefault,2000); 

function setToDefault()
{  window.location = window.location.hash="tabs-28";  }
```

This changes the address in the url bar but the page doesn't go anywhere. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe adding location.reload() to it after you set the hash?

Answer (score 0):

You're unclear if you're already on the 'original' page when you run that JavaScript, but you're trying to set `window.location` without a URL, so I am assuming you are already on that correct page and are trying to display another tab:

If you're using jQuery Tabs, set the hash for history, then use the `select()` method:

```
window.location.hash = "tabs-28";   // only returns 'tabs-28' back, which is
                                    // why setting it to window.location then
                                    // doesn't work

var index = ???;                    // ??? = whatever the tab index is
myTabElement.tabs("select", index)  // use the jQuery Tab library to switch to
                                    // the desired tab
```

If you're not on the original page that has the tabs, then on the 'thank you' page:

```
window.location.hash = "originalpage.html#tabs-28";
```

And on then back on the 'original' page:

```
jQuery(function({ 
    if (window.location.hash != '') {
        var myTabElement = jQuery('#whateverTabElementIs'),
            index = ???; 
            // ??? = however you figure the index based on current window.location.hash
        myTabElement.tabs("select", index);
    } 
}));
```

*OR* if you want when you're initializing the tabs element in the first place

```
jQuery( "#whateverTabElementIs" ).tabs({ selected: ??? });
// ??? = however you figure the index based on current window.location.hash
```